# My app downloads decreased very unexpectedly more than 10x times

Tags: java, android

My android app was going satisfactory since 5-6 months and since a month the downloads has decreased so much dramatically that it is very frustrating and depressing. I neither updated the app nor made any changes to app's page since 3 months. Android vital are good, just about 0.3% of both ANR and Crashes and all downloads that came are organic ones till now. I even checked the keywords and ranks are as usual. My app shows on search with keyword like (App Name) + (Developer Name (removing last 's' alphabet) ), but not with (App Name)+ (Developer Name).

For eg- shows with "Music Player Sonic app" where "Music Player" is app name and "Sonic apps" is developer name.

But does not show with "Music Player Sonic apps". This used to show before this incident happened.

I heard many developers faced it and happened a year ago too. Now this year I have faced it, did those developer recover from this event last year. I don't know what to do as this is only source of income for my living. Please see the image too. Any words will be highly appreciated.
(One thing I notice is "Similar apps" section is not shown in home page of my app where as for other its shows. )

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry this happened to you, but I'm not sure this is the right site for this sort of post. It doesn't seem like you have a question we can answer.

Comment: your question is not related to programming or app development, but rather *how google play store works*, therefore is off-topic here.

Comment: You may want to check out if such posts are allowed on the android developer subreddits, and post there. I recall seeing similar posts on one of those, though a solution does not come to mind.

Comment: What a pity. What can we do for you?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry for you , this is the worst nightmare to any app developer , but this is not the end . for the reason , there are a lot of reasons to why your app downloads are decreasing

1. Algorithm Changes
2. Low-Quality App
3. Poor Monetization
4. Neglected ASO
5. New Competitors
6. Keyword Shifts
7. Black Hat Practices

for more information please check this [link](https://www.mobileaction.co/blog/app-store-optimization/app-downloads-dropping-aso/)